# In R, sum over all rows above a given row and restarting at new ID?

Tags: r, sum, conditional-statements, plyr

The following is what I have:

> ID Year Score 
>   1  1999 10 
>   1  2000 11 
>   1  2001 14 
>   1  2002 22 
>   2  2000 19 
>   2  2001 17 
>   2  2002 22 
>   3  1998 10 
>   3  1999 12

The following is what I would like to do:

> ID Year Score Total 
>   1  1999 10 10 
>   1  2000 11 21 
>   1  2001 14 35 
>   1  2002 22 57 
>   2  2000 19 19
>   2  2001 17 36 
>   2  2002 22 48 
>   3  1998 10 10 
>   3  1999 12 22

The amount of years and the specific years vary for each Id.

I have a feeling that it's some advanced options in ddply but I have not been able to find the answer. I've also tried working with for/while loops but since these are dreadfully slow in R and my data-set is large, it's not working all that well.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `sumsum` function and apply it with `ave` to all subgroups.

```
transform(dat, Total = ave(Score, ID, FUN = cumsum))

  ID Year Score Total
1  1 1999    10    10
2  1 2000    11    21
3  1 2001    14    35
4  1 2002    22    57
5  2 2000    19    19
6  2 2001    17    36
7  2 2002    22    58
8  3 1998    10    10
9  3 1999    12    22
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I ended up using Sven Hohenstein's answer but it looks like all of these will work. I will look more into ddply using your guys' examples.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is large, then `ddply` will be slow.

`data.table` is the way to go.

```
 library(data.table)
 DT <- data.table(dat)
 # create your desired column in `DT`
 DT[, agg.Score := cumsum(Score), by = ID]
```